# add a space after the comment delimiter

Tags: comment

When I'm writing a comment and press `M-j` to continue the comment on the next line (using single-line comments), if I press it multiple times say because I want to leave the next comment line "empty" for separation, the cursor ends up appearing right after the comment delimiter. Instead, I always want the cursor to be separated from the comment delimiter by one space. I'd like this to be the case in every mode, globally if possible.

As an example, if I have this:

```
;; comment|
```

If I press `M-j` I get this:

```
;; comment
;; |
```

It's correctly separated from the comment delimiter by one space.

If without doing anything else I press `M-j` again, I get this:

```
;; comment
;;
;;|
```

So from then on there is no space added between the comment delimiter and the cursor. I want there to *always* be a space of separation.

By comparison, in c++-mode I *always* get the space.

I'd like to know if there's a way to get this in other modes (or even all other modes) before I resort to hacking it in by wrapping the function myself.

**EDIT**: I ended up advising `comment-indent-new-line` to add one space if there aren't any spaces following the comment-start:

```
(define-advice comment-indent-new-line
    (:after (&optional soft) at-least-one-space)
  "Ensure that at least one space is added after the comment-start."
  (let ((start (regexp-quote comment-start)))
    (when (and (nth 4 (syntax-ppss))
               (looking-back start (+ (point) (length start)))
               (not (looking-back " "  (+ (point) 1))))
      (insert " "))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this issue.  It is caused because in `emacs-lisp-mode`, `comment-start` is ";" whereas in `c++-mode`, it is "// " (note the space).  The obvious fix would be to add a space to `comment-start` in `emacs-lisp-mode`.  Unfortunately, this will break many lisp functions which assume that `comment-start` does not contain a space.

The best solution I've found is to use this advice.  You should probably change it to use nadvice.el instead of the old advice system.

```
(defadvice comment-indent-new-line (after just-one-space-after-comment activate)
  "Make sure that `comment-indent-new-line' does not insert extra spaces."
  (when (and (looking-back comment-start)
             (not (looking-back " ")))
    (just-one-space)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your response. I wanted to see if there was a way that I could set some variable perhaps or something to get this behavior before I went off to advising a function. I wish I could see what was responsible for why it works as I want in c++-mode.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña See my edit.  Unfortunately, if you change the variable in question, it will cause other undesireable behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I hesitate to use this advice though because it seems like it'd always force a single space. If I have the comment-text indented and I press `M-j`, it continues the comment with the same indentation, which I like. It seems like this would force there to be a single space? I ended up creating my own advice which adds one space if there aren't any spaces after the comment-start, which I think is more flexible.

Comment: Indentation inside comments works for me with that advice. Note that the test (not (looking-back " ")) prevents it from being applied if there are already spaces after the comment.

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: I wonder though why the first time I press `M-j` it does add a space? I think what happens is it takes on the same indentation as the previous comment, which was one space, but when you press `M-j` again without typing anything, that's considered a comment with no spaces behind it/no indentation, so the third comment doesn't have any indentation.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña That's right.  If you run `M-j` with only whitespace on the first line you'll also get that result.